# CCScrollView does't receive touches (Cocos2d V 3.0)

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, ccscrollview, cocos2d-iphone-3

I try to add CCScrollView with paging (cocos2d- iphone v3.0). But it's not working. 
It doesn't call any delegate methods (for example scrollViewDidScroll:).

```
CCNode *cards = [CCNode node];
for (int i = 0 ; i < 3; i++) {
    CCLabelTTF *label = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"label %d", i] fontName:@"Arial" fontSize:24];
    label.color = [CCColor redColor];
    label.position = ccp(winSize.width * i + winSize.width * 0.5 , winSize.height * 0.5);
    [cards addChild:label];
}
self.scrollView = [[CCScrollView alloc] initWithContentNode:cards];
self.scrollView.contentSizeType = CCSizeTypeNormalized;
self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(3, 1);
self.scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
self.scrollView.delegate = self;
self.scrollView.position = CGPointZero;
self.scrollView.anchorPoint = CGPointZero;
[self addChild:self.scrollView];
```

Answer (score 0):

You actually need to set the `contentSize` of the `contentNode` of the `scrollView` as opposed to the `contentSize` of the `scrollView`.

In `CCScrollView.h`

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) CCNode* contentNode;
```

So you should replace this part of the code:

```
self.scrollView.contentSizeType = CCSizeTypeNormalized;
self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(3, 1);
```

With this:

```
self.scrollView.contentNode.contentSizeType = CCSizeTypeNormalized;
self.scrollView.contentNode.contentSize = CGSizeMake(3, 1);
```

Comment: It doesn't help :(
As I understand, problem isn't in delegates methods. Even GestureRecognizers methods don't call. I mean handlePan: and handleTap:. But I don't know, what is wrong

Comment: My guess is that there is something else in your project interfering with this, since I have tested your code with my change in a new project and everything works fine.

Comment: Yes, thank. I inherited parent from CCNode, and when I change it to CCScene, scrollView works correctly.